# UISwitch returns NULL?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, null

I have a UISwitch that returns `(null)` for some reason. Below is my code:

AddAlbumViewController:

```
// .h 
IBOutlet UISwitch *photostreamSwitch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *photostreamSwitch;

// .m
@synthesize photostreamSwitch;
photostreamSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
NSLog(@"photostreamSwitch: %@", photostreamSwitch); // returns a not-null value
```

SecondViewController:

```
//.m
- (IBAction)createAlbum:(id)sender {
AddAlbumViewController *addAlbumViewController = [[AddAlbumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddAlbum" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
NSLog(@"Test Switch: %@",addAlbumViewController.photostreamSwitch); // returns null
[addAlbumViewController release];
}
```

I think I have everything set up right. If this helps, AddAlbumViewController is inside a UINavigationController and SecondViewController contains the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view controller is created but its view (i.e. its nib) is not loaded yet, therefore the property isn't connected yet. You can force the nib to load by accessing the view member of the controller:

```
- (IBAction)createAlbum:(id)sender {
    AddAlbumViewController *addAlbumViewController = [[AddAlbumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddAlbum" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIView* tempView = addAlbumViewController.view;
    NSLog(@"Test Switch: %@",addAlbumViewController.photostreamSwitch); // no longer null
    [addAlbumViewController release];
}
```

Comment: That did it! Now, if I add it in my viewDidLoad, it detects correctly. (isOn). But if I put it in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, it doesn't. Here's my code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath: `photostreamSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(199, 8, 0, 0)]; [cell.contentView addSubview:photostreamSwitch]; [photostreamSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];` Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe you could post more code.